# soap address being changed when access through IIS proxy

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

I am using IIS 7.5 and redirect all request to weblogic server.
 My IIS is running on https and weblogic on http protocol.

when I access webservices exposed over weblogic through below URL

```
https://10.AA.BB.CC/XXX/YYYYY?WSDL
```

I am able to receive wsdl but the soap address is changed to below

```
<soap:address location="http://10.AA.BB.CC:80/XXX/YYYYY"/>
```

which is on http and we have not provide port 80 access to our client.

expected soap adderss shoud be

```
<soap:address location="https://10.AA.BB.CC:80/XXX/YYYYY"/>

Client(access https url)---->IIS(https)----->Weblogic(http)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set an extra header variable "WL-Proxy-SSL: true" at the load balancer so that WLS identifies the request is called on https. Also, you need to set the flag Weblogic-Proxy-Plugin Enabled at the WLS managed server.